# MS Word tries to uncapitalize a word in the middle of my sentence

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, autocorrect

I am writing in first person as an entity made of several entities...a collection of entities. I use the word "We" often. I capitalize it to indicate that the entities are speaking. As a proper pronoun it should be capitalized. Word tries to uncapitalize it every time. Is there a way to make a rule for this to not happen?

Comment: `As a proper pronoun it should be capitalized` wrong. Only English `I` is an exception

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc My guess is he's writing a novel, when such exceptions are perfectly valid.